# Are hallucinations a requirement for Schizophrenia?

Tags: schizophrenia, hallucinations

The symptom most people think about when hearing "Schizophrenia" is hallucination. However, [ICD-10's entry for schizophrenia](http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2010/en#/F20) seems to list auditory hallucinations as just one of many possible symptoms.

In practice, are hallucinations a **required** symptom for a diagnosis of Schizophrenia, or can a diagnosis be made based on other symptoms?

Comment: I'm too lazy to walk down three floors and pick up the ICD-10 research criteria and DSM-5 right now, but usually the diagnostic criteria give a list of possible symptoms of which a certain number, **but not all**, must be met. I don't remember the IDC 10 criteria, but I know for a fact that the DSM-5 does **not require** the patient to have hallucinations for a diagnosis of Schizophrenia, because this has been asked before and I looked it up then.

Comment: If you desperately need the complete criteria, post a note and I'll look it up.

Comment: @what I linked to the ICD-10 entry in the question, though it is still unclear to me which (or how many of) the symptoms are _required_. Moreover, _Schizophrenia_ seems to be a larger category with more subtypes under it, making the answer to my question more difficult to find.

Answer (score 5):

No – at least, they shouldn't be required. [Wikipedia describes the DSM-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizophrenia#Criteria) as requiring "delusions, hallucinations, or disorganized speech". Delusions are distinct from hallucinations in that they aren't necessarily perceptual in a conventional sense, though both diverge a person's conscious experience from empirical reality. Disorganized speech is characteristic of [disorganized / hebephrenic schizophrenia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disorganized_schizophrenia), regarding which Wikipedia states:

> The most prominent features of disorganized schizophrenia are not delusions and hallucinations, as they are in paranoid schizophrenia,<sup>[[5](http://schizophrenia.about.com/od/whatisschizophrenia/f/schiz_diagnosis.htm)][[6](http://counsellingresource.com/lib/distress/schizophrenic/schizophrenia-icd/hebephrenic/)]</sup> although fragmentary delusions and hallucinations may be present.

This doesn't seem to be the only (partial) exception to the rule you ask about, and [your source mentions it too](http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2010/en#/F20.1): "Affective changes are prominent, delusions and hallucinations fleeting and fragmentary".

Answer (score 4):

According to the [DSM V](https://ia800900.us.archive.org/0/items/info_munsha_DSM5/DSM-5.pdf), for the diagnosis of schizophrenia, the following is necessary:

> two (or more) of the following, each present for a significant portion of time during a 1-month period (or less if successfully treated):
> (1) Delusions
> (2) Hallucinations
> (3) Disorganized speech
> (4) Grossly disorganized or catatonic behavior
> (5) Negative symptoms, i.e., affective flattening, alogia, or avolition.

where one of the symptoms **must** be delusions, hallucinations, **or** disorganized speech. So, **no**, hallucinations do not need to be present.

Answer (score 0):

No. Hallucinations are not necessarily present, although they use to be observed or reported. Hebephrenic schizophrenia does not have hallucinations as a main symptom, and simple schizophrenia doesn't have them at all. The criteria are very clear.

Comment: Your mention of simple schizophrenia is an interesting contribution, but [not without controversy as a diagnosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple-type_schizophrenia#Criticisms).

Comment: In fact, exactly as it happens with many other diagnosis. One must know they can be criticized too.

Comment: I'll rephrase: the controversy regarding the diagnostic validity of simple schizophrenia seems much greater than that surrounding other forms of schizophrenia.